# Redirect Loop When Enabling SSL on Matching URI Slug

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to accomplish 2 tasks with mod_rewrite:

1. If the URL, regardless of protocol, does not have the "www" subdomain, then add "www" to the URL.
2. If the URI begins with /secure.php AND the protocol is NOT https, then switch the protocol to https.

So I tried:

```
# Redirect to www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force SSL for secure.php URIs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/secure.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I get a redirect loop when accessing /secure.php URIs. I can't figure out what the problem is, this is how I see the sequence of events:

1. http://mysite.com/secure.php is requested
2. The host name does **not** contain "www", so it passes the first condition
3. The URL is updated to http://www.mysite.com/secure.php, and the process loops back to the top.
4. The host name **does** contain "www", so it fails the first condition and skips the rewrite.
5. HTTPS **is** off, so it matches the next condition, AND
6. The URI begins with "/secure.php", so it matches **both** required conditions
7. The URL is updated to https://www.mysite.com/secure.php, and the process loops back to the top.
8. The host name **does** contain "www", so it fails the first condition, and skips the rewrite.
9. HTTPS **is not** off, so it fails the next condition and skips the rewrite.

Have I got that right? What am I doing wrong here?

I also have one other rule in .htaccess for removing index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

So here's the entire .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove index.php from ExpressionEngine URIs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Redirect to www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force SSL for /secure.php URIs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/secure.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your sequence of events is pretty close to [the real process](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html), but that's irrelevant in this case as your conclusion is correct, in my opinion. I can't see any reason for a loop either. Is that all or there are more rules somewhere? If that's all, where are the `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` directives? Is `FollowSymlinks` enabled, i.e `Options +FollowSymlinks`?

Comment: I do have `RewriteEngine On` set, but not `RewriteBase`. `FollowSymlinks` is not enabled via the .htaccess file - not sure about the server itself. I do have one other rule in the file, which I've added to my question.

Comment: Where is the last rule-set you added to the question, before or after the other rules? Please put them in the original order including all directives.

Comment: I've added the full .htaccess file to my question (and added `RewriteBase`) - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The server variables like `HTTP_HOST` or `REQUEST_URI` are available in a `RewriteCond`, but not in a `RewriteRule`. If you need these variables you must capture them in a RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)
RewriteRule .* http://www.%1/$0 [R,L]
```

You don't need to check for `secure.php` in a RewriteCond, you can just specify it in the RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(secure.php.*) https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

OT: Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the help Olaf. I tried your code, but I'm still getting a redirect loop on the /secure.php URLs.

Comment: @kgrote I cannot see, how this might happen, unless you have other conflicting rules. If you have access to your apache configuration files, you can activate `RewriteLog` to see, where it is going wrong.